# "Java not found" when using tabula-py linux mint

Tags: python, java, linux, module

I was trying to run a program using pycharm where I also imported tabula and when I ran the program it gave me this error `Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "/home/dawit/IaaAgDataNER/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabula/io.py", line 80, in _run`

`result = subprocess.run(`

`File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:`

`File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__ self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,`

`File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)`

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java'`

Which type of java do I need to install (currently it's OpenJDK) and how do I change the path to somewhere where it doesn't require root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `tabula-py` but I think you should specify full path of `java` executable file in your `subprocess.run`, example:

```bash
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

```py
result = subprocess.run("/usr/bin/java ...", shell=True, check=True)
```

Get full path to `java` executable file by running `which java`. Then specify the full path into `subprocess.run`.

Also, check [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3) for more details.